Existence of a minimizer for the Thomas-Fermi-type model
I am looking for the following minimization problem
$$
\inf\left\{\int_{\mathbb R^d}f^3-\int_{\mathbb R^d}f^2:0\leq f \in L^1\cap L^3(\mathbb R^d), \int_{\mathbb R^d}f = 1\right\}
$$
where $d$ denoted the dimension. It is known that the above value if negative, by a scaling argument. Furthermore, any minimizer, if it exists, is radially symmetric, by rearrangement inequality.
I am wondering if there exists a minimizer?

Let's put $a=\int f^3\text d x$ and $b=\int f^2\text d x$, then $a-b\geq -\frac{b^2}{4a}$ by AM-GM inequality ($a+\frac{b^2}{4a}\geq b$ since $a\frac{b^2}{4a}=(\frac b 2)^2$) and moreover $b^2\leq a$ by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality applied to $f^{3/2}$ and $f^{1/2}$, so $\inf\geq -\frac 1 4$.
This value is actually attained by any function of the form $ \frac 1 {|E|}1_E$ where $E\subset \mathbb R^d$ is a measurable set such that $|E|=2$.
Edit:
To answer the comment, if we still call $a$ and $b$ the two terms we get $$a-b\geq -(p-q)\sqrt[p-q]{\frac{(q-1)^{q-1}}{(p-1)^{p-1}}}\sqrt[p-q]{\frac{b^{p-1}}{a^{q-1}}} \geq  -(p-q)\sqrt[p-q]{\frac{(q-1)^{q-1}}{(p-1)^{p-1}}}$$ where the first step follows from finding the minimum of $ax^{p-1}-bx^{q-1}$ for $x\geq 0$ and the second one follows from the log-convexity of the norms (Proof of the log-convexity of $L^p$ norms) applied to the exponents $q$, $1$ and $p$ with the right constant $\theta$ (which is $\frac{p(q-1)}{q(p-1)}$). The equality is attained for functions of the form $\frac 1 {|E|} 1_E$ with $|E|=\sqrt[p-q]{\frac{p-1}{q-1}}$.
I had this idea because the first step is what you get by rescaling a function, and probably I've have been a bit lucky with the second step actually working.

Cool! I agree with the result, but can you please expand on the AM-GM inequality?

It might be a special case where $f^2$ is controlled by $f^3$ by AM-GM simply. Does result still valid if $f^3$ and $f^2$ are replaced respectively by $f^p$ and $f^q$ (with $p>q>1$)?

I edited the answer. @Muniain

OK. It's awesome. Does one have any proof by calculus of variational method?

The minimizing sequence is radially symmetric. But I am not sure if this can be used to deduce the compactness of minimizing sequence.

Matteo Gori's solution is both elegant and correct.
Here's approach based on variational calculus to derive the form of a minimizer. It's not exactly what you're asking, but I'm putting this out here for reference of an alternate path to finding the form of the minimizer.
Assuming the inf is attained, i.e. there is at least one minimizer (this would take some work to prove), then Lagrange multipliers can help you characterize it.
Let $f$ be a minimizer, and let $E$ be the set of $x\in\mathbb R^d$ where $f(x) \neq 0$ (the support). Then writing the Lagrangian
$$\mathcal L(f) = \int_{\mathbb R^d} f^3 - \int_{\mathbb R^d} f^2 - \lambda \int_{\mathbb R^d} f$$ with $\lambda \geq 0$, and setting its partial derivative (w.r.t. to $f(x)$) to zero, we obtain that for all $x\in E$,
$$3f^2(x)-2f(x)-\lambda=0$$
Thus $f(x)$ is is one of the two roots of the polynomial $P(X) = 3X^2-2X-\lambda$.
$$f(x)=\frac{2\pm\sqrt{4+12\lambda}}{6}$$
But since we know $f(x)\geq 0$, we must have that $f(x)=\frac{2+\sqrt{4+12\lambda}}{6}$. In other words, $f$ is constant on $E$. From there on, using the constraint that $f$ sums to 1, you can deduce that $$f=\frac 1 {|E|} 1_E$$
Finally, plugging that back into the function to minimize, it's easy to see that the minimum is achieved if and only if $|E|=2$.

Is constant function the unique minimizer?

Yes, by the Lagrange Multipliers, we show above that if a minimizer $f$ exists, then it can only assume 2 values, $0$ and $1/|E|$ (where $E$ is the support of $f$).
